# SQL Query is not retrieving PersonContactId

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, marketing-cloud-connect

Marketing Cloud is connected to Service Cloud by the Connector: synchronized entities Accounts, Contacts (and 5 others).

**GOAL: I want to create a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud that ONLY retrieves PersonAccounts where Receive_Newsletter__c = 1. I will use this DE to e-mail my clients.**

I performed the following steps:

1. Duplicated the Synchronized DE Accounts_Salesforce (thereby creating a new DE)
2. Created an Automation with SQL Query Activity to 'update' this new DE based on the data in Salesforce (Accounts where Receive_Newsletter__c = 1)

By doing so I am able to overwrite the DE every hour by automation with the actual data in Service Cloud.

Unfortunately, my SQL Query is not performing as expected. I am supposed to obtain 25,097 records.

It retrieves the right data (records = 25097) when I use below SQL Query:

```
SELECT Id, PersonEmail
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE Receive_Newsletter__c = 1
```

It retrieves the wrong data (records = 6) when I use below SQL Query

```
SELECT Id, PersonEmail, PersonContactId
FROM Account_Salesforce
WHERE Receive_Newsletter__c = 1
```

These 6 records are the records for which Receive_Newsletter__c was updated to 1 **TODAY**.

I need PersonContactId seeing as it is my SubscriberKey everywhere.

Please help me to understand what is going wrong? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you run reports in Service Cloud, do you get 25,097 records WHERE Receive_Newsletter__c = 1? Also please check the resulting DE field lengths to confirm if they are same as Account Sync DEs.

Comment: @BradSapkota Thank you for the reply! Yes, when I run reports in Service Cloud with a filter Receive_Newsletter__c = 1 I receive 25,097 records. 
I did notice that the target DE field lengths are 50 characters, in comparison to Account Sync DE 18 characters field lengths. Could this be the cause?

Comment: @BradSapkota   changing the field lengths did not make a difference unfortunately.